# I have a Sharepoint site and I want to create a Q&A section, not FAQ, how can I do this?

Tags: 2010

I'm profficeient in html so that's not a problem if it invovles some coding. I've seen others use a custom list for FAQ but that isn't the type of thing I want to create.

Any suggestions would be great.